# Where can I find Celery logs in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm working on a simple web app that runs a python script which can take about 5-10 minutes. Instead of making the user wait on the site, I run the job in the background using Celery and send the user an email notification when the script is complete.

My question is straightforward: where are the logs for Celery job? Currently, if the job fails because it runs into a fatal error, I don't have any way of knowing.

The [Celery Logging Docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/tasks.html?highlight=logging#logging) show how to set up the logs, but it's not entirely clear to me where I can access the logs (I want to save as a file) after the job is complete.

app.py

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Imports
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, send_file, redirect, url_for    
from werkzeug import secure_filename
import logging
from logging import Formatter, FileHandler
from forms import *

import my_module
from tasks import make_celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# App Config.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

celery = make_celery(app)
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

format = "%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename='app-errors.log', 
                    filemode='a',
                    format=format,
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger(__name__).addHandler(console)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Controllers.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

@celery.task
def background_task(formdict):
    logger.debug('starting work...')
    result = my_module.main(formdict)
    return result

@app.route('/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        task = background_task.delay(form.data)

        return redirect(url_for('jobcomplete'))
    else:
        print form.errors
        filename = None
    return render_template('pages/home.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Quote: "Celery uses the standard Python logger library, for which documentation can be found in the logging module." You should continue reading there in order to configure the logging.

Comment: how are you running the celery worker? how is logging configured?

Comment: @blahblahblah Please let me know if you found the answer to this. I want to send this log on Kibana and therefore want to send to the standard output stream.